# System cannot find dll

Tags: c#, .net

I have a dll called test and within test.dll, I'm referencing another dll called process. Now when I try loading test.dll, I get the error "System cannot find process.dll.
Please help

```
Assembly u = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\test\test.dll");

        Type t = u.GetType("Test.Process");
        MethodInfo m = t.GetMethod("ProcessFile");

        try
        {
            object[] myparam = new object[1];
            myparam[0] = @"C:\test\testFile.csv";

            result = (string)m.Invoke(null, myparam);

            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.ToString());
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100000);
        }
```

Comment: System cannot find process.dll or System cannot find test.dll?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you want [`LoadFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx) instead of `LoadFile` in this case. The difference is that the extra path (`c:\test`) will be added to the "load from" context which will then be used for dependencies such as `process.dll`.

At the moment, it's trying to resolve `process.dll` without taking `c:\test` into consideration. Read the linked documentation for more information.

Comment: Another problem, when I try loading the dll from another computer that has no Visual Studio installed, I get an error - Cannot find dll file specified. Please any ideas as to what is going on?

Comment: @Jay: You'll have to give more details - what *exactly* are you trying to do? Run the executable on one machine, but load another over the network? At what point does it fail? It sounds like you should ask this in another question.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`LoadFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28) instead of [`LoadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b61s44e8.aspx). Quote from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b61s44e8.aspx):

> Use the LoadFile method to load and examine assemblies that have the
>   same identity, but are located in different paths. LoadFile does not
>   load files into the LoadFrom context, and does not resolve
>   dependencies using the load path, as the LoadFrom method does.
>   LoadFile is useful in this limited scenario because LoadFrom cannot be
>   used to load assemblies that have the same identities but different
>   paths; it will load only the first such assembly.

```
Assembly u = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\test\test.dll");
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Get test.dll fileInfo:

```
 FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo("test.dll");
```

and use fullName to load the assembly:

```
Assembly assem = Assembly.LoadFile(fileInfo.FullName);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Anyway, I think you should use LoadFrom instead of LoadFile too.